# Trying to use gglocator in ggplot2: Error in vpPathFromVector(names)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to use the gglocator function in `ggmap`. I get the following error:

```
Error in vpPathFromVector(names) : 
A viewport path must contain at least one viewport name
```

I found it when trying to use gglocator with ggmaps, but the same error happens with ggplot2 alone. Here is an example of how it would come up:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggmap)
df <- data.frame(xvar = 1:10, yvar = 1:10)
qplot(xvar, yvar, data = df) + annotate(geom = 'point', x = 3, y = 6)
gglocator(4)

Error in vpPathFromVector(names) : 
A viewport path must contain at least one viewport name
```

I'm using RStudio v 0.96.331 on Windows 7. I have the latest version of ggplot2.

Comment: I wonder if need changes to ggplot have broken the code for this function.  Did you try to contact the package's maintainer: David Kahle david.kahle@gmail.com?

Comment: No, I haven't. I'm pretty new at this stuff, so I figured it's most likely something I've done wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I have same viewport error message using gglocator (Windows XP).

Transferred previous version of ggplot2 and gmap folders 
to the R library and gglocator now works fine again.

Sorry, in too much of a rush to verify which versions were
used, but could submit if needed.

My hunch is that the gglocator problem is in the ggplot2 that
I updated today ( Oct 27, 2012).

Comment: will you please mention the ggplot2 version that you downgraded to, to solve the error?

Comment: only just seen your question after checking if I could run later versions of ggmap
and ggplot2. I've downgraded to ggplot 0.9.1 and gglocator works fine again (Windows XP).